# Scroll Over Ad Control - Windows Phone UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp

I am using ad control in my xaml as below

```
<Page
x:Class="namespace"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:namespace"
xmlns:ViewModels="using:namespace.ViewModels"
xmlns:common="using:namespace.Classes"
xmlns:stringBind="using:namespace.Classes"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:q42controls="using:Q42.WinRT.Controls"
xmlns:UI="using:Microsoft.Advertising.WinRT.UI"
Background="Gray"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Page.Resources>
    <ViewModels:ArticleViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
    <DataTemplate x:Key="headerTest">
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="pivotTemplate">
        <StackPanel Margin="-15 0 -15 0">
            <Grid>
                <Image x:Name="PlaceHolderImage" Source="Assets/PlaceHolder.jpg"></Image>
                <Image q42controls:ImageExtensions.CacheUri="{Binding ImageURL}" Tag="{Binding ImageURL}" Tapped="ImageView"></Image>
            </Grid>
            <StackPanel Background="White">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding UpdatedDate}" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" Pivot.SlideInAnimationGroup="GroupTwo" Margin="10 10 0 10" 
                           FontFamily="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"
                           Foreground="#777"></TextBlock>
                <Border VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="1" Background="Black" Opacity="0.1">
                </Border>
                <TextBlock x:Name="HeadLine" Text="{Binding HeadLine}"  
                                           Margin="10 5 10 -5" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                           FontSize="{Binding HeadlineFontSize}" Foreground="Black"
                                           FontFamily="{StaticResource HeadlineCommonFamiy}"
                                           Pivot.SlideInAnimationGroup="GroupTwo"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Abstract}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{Binding AbstractFontSize}"
                               Pivot.SlideInAnimationGroup="GroupTwo" Margin="10 5 10 10"
                               Foreground="#999"
                                       FontFamily="{StaticResource AbstractCommonFamily}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel x:Name="descriptionSP" Background="White">
                <Image Source="Assets/PlaceHolder.jpg" Width="300" Height="250"></Image>
                <UI:AdControl
                    AutoRefreshIntervalInSeconds="60"
                    ApplicationId="3f83fe91-d6be-434d-a0ae-7351c5a997f1"
                    AdUnitId="10865270"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Height="250"
                    IsAutoRefreshEnabled="True"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Margin="5,-240,5,5"
                    Width="300"
                    ErrorOccurred="AdControl_ErrorOccurred"/>
                <RichTextBlock IsTextSelectionEnabled="False" x:Name="richTextBlock" 
                               local:Properties.Html="{Binding ArticleDetail}" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                               FontSize="{Binding FontSize}"
                               Pivot.SlideInAnimationGroup="GroupTwo" Margin="10,10,10,-20"
                                       FontFamily="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}">
                </RichTextBlock>
                <Image Source="Assets/PlaceHolder.jpg" Width="300" Height="250"></Image>
                <UI:AdControl
                    AutoRefreshIntervalInSeconds="60"
                    ApplicationId="3f83fe91-d6be-434d-a0ae-7351c5a997f1"
                    AdUnitId="10865270"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Height="250"
                    IsAutoRefreshEnabled="True"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"                        
                    Margin="5,-220,5,5"
                    Width="300" Loaded="AdControl_Loaded"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar Foreground="Black" Background="White">
        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton x:Uid="Share" Click="Share_Click" Label="Share">
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <BitmapIcon UriSource="/Assets/Share.png" Height="30" Margin="0,-5,0,0"/>
                </AppBarButton.Icon>
            </AppBarButton>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Favorite" Name="favIcon" Click="Favorite_Click" Label="Favorite" Margin="0,-2,0,0"></AppBarButton>
        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
<Grid Background="#f2f2f2" x:Name="grid">
    <Grid x:Name="LoadingGrid" Visibility="Visible">
        <ProgressRing x:Name="progressRing" IsActive="True" Foreground="#d03438" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="60"
                      Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 20 0 0"></ProgressRing>
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image x:Name="logoImage" Grid.Row="0" Source="Assets/18600.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,0"></Image>
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="swipeBetweenPages" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <Pivot DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}" x:Name="pivot" Margin="0,-45,0,0" 
                             HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource headerTest}" 
                   ItemTemplate="{StaticResource pivotTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Articles}" SelectionChanged="pivot_SelectionChanged">
            </Pivot>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
    <Grid  Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Black" Name="popUp">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Image Source="/Assets/Close_White.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="1" Tapped="CloseImage"></Image>
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="scroll" ZoomMode="Enabled" Grid.Row="2">
            <Image x:Name="popUpImage" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,-50,0,0"></Image>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

By using the above xaml piece of code, I can render ad properly, But i cant scroll the page when i scroll over the ad control. Please someone guide to solve the issue. Any help on this would be very much helpful to solve the issue

Expected output

[image: Image For Clarification]

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should see the AdControl as it would be an iframe on a web page. Scrolling inside the AdControl isn't part of your page.

Comment: @Bart Thank you for the response. I am not using any web page. I am using an ad control in windows phone. I used ad control inside the stack panel.

Comment: I have put an `AdControl` in a `StackPanel` which was wrapped inside a `ScrollViewer` but it works as expected and I can normally scroll even when the mouse hovers the control. Could you post some specific info about when this happens or more XAML?

Comment: @MZetko Thank you for the response i have updated my question with my full XAML code. Please review and guide me where i did the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By using the above xaml piece of code, I can render ad properly, But i cant scroll the page when i scroll over the ad control.

You need to set the height of your `ScrollViewer` explicitly:

```
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image x:Name="logoImage" Grid.Row="0" Source="Assets/18600.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,0"></Image>
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="swipeBetweenPages" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Visible" Height="300">//here I set the height of ScrollViewer to 300
            <Pivot DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}" x:Name="pivot" Margin="0,-45,0,0" 
                         HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource headerTest}" 
               ItemTemplate="{StaticResource pivotTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Articles}" SelectionChanged="pivot_SelectionChanged">
            </Pivot>
        </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

I set the ScrollViewer's height to 300 and when the Content's height is bigger than 300. ScrollViewer will show correctly.

**Update:** Here is the complete demo: [AdControlSample](https://github.com/elvisxia/AdControlSample)

To show the Pivot Header you need to set the margin of Pivot Control to `Margin="0,0,0,0"` and also you need to fill your defined header template headerTest:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="headerTest">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding HeadLine}"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="pivotTemplate">
    ...
```

Fix the margin:

```
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image x:Name="logoImage" Grid.Row="0" Source="Assets/18600.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,0"></Image>
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="swipeBetweenPages" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Visible">
            <Pivot  x:Name="pivot" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                         HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource headerTest}" 
               ItemTemplate="{StaticResource pivotTemplate}"  SelectionChanged="pivot_SelectionChanged">
            </Pivot>
        </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

And here is the result:
[image]

Comment: I posted the complete demo that I tried with your xaml codes and the result. Please have a check.

Comment: Thank you for the sample code. But as for my requirement i don't want any scroller, i should swipe over the ad like we are swiping the page

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding your requirement, I've fixed my answer and uploaded a new demo. Please check my update.

Comment: i cannot vertical scroll up the page over the ad.

Comment: I got confused, what do you mean by scroll up the page over the ad?

Comment: I have updated my question with an image please look into this and guide me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124405/discussion-between-anbarasi-and-elvis-xia-msft).

Comment: The pages of Pivot Control should be switched by clicking the headers. You can't switch the pages by scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `ScrollViewer` inside the `PivotItem`'s `DataTemplate`.

Currently the `ScrollViewer` wraps the whole `Pivot`, but the pivot itself handles the scroll event which means the `ScrollViewer` does not receive it. You can confirm this when you hover the scroll bar with your mouse and scroll - in this case it will work, because the mouse is no longer inside the `Pivot` itself.

The solution would look like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="pivotTemplate">
    <ScrollViewer>
       <StackPanel Margin="-15 0 -15 0">
          ...
       </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: And have you removed the original ScrollViewer which is around the Pivot itself? The one with x:Name="swipeBetweenPages"

Comment: yes i removed scroll viewer named with swipeBetweenPages